# Valores inteiros no terminal

Tags: c++, int

Preciso fazer a soma dos números ímpares entre 2 valores. Em compiladores online o código funciona como previsto, somando quaisquer valores impares de entrada e dando a saída esperada, porém no meu terminal (4.15.0-34-generic) ao colocar, por exemplo, 6 e -5, o resultado sai algo em torno de 32655, como se tivesse chegado ao limite do `int`, que eu chequei na internet e não é nem próximo de -5 o limite negativo do `int`.

```
    #include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main() {

    int x,y,r;
    cin>>x>>y;
    if(x<y) {
        for (x; x<y ; x++){
            if(x%2 == 0) {
                continue;
            }
            else {
                r += x;
            }
        }
        }
    else {
            for (y; y<x ; y++){
                if(y%2 == 0) {
                    continue;
                }
                else {
                    r += y;
                }
        }

    }

    cout<<r<<endl;


    return 0; }
```

O código é este, está em C++.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Provavelmente o problema é que não inicializou a variável `r` com 0. Então pega lixo na memória. Como os compiladores online precisam de ambientes controlados eles tem grande chance de ter o 0 na memória e funciona por coincidência. Não programe para funcionar, programe para estar certo. Espero que isto lhe ensine que não pode confiar no resultado apresentado, porque ele pode estar certo só por coincidência. Temos muitos programas rodando por aí que "param de funcionar do nada", por a coincidência deixou de existir. programar não é ver se funciona, é provar que funciona sempre, em todas situações. Organizando e simplificando o código ficaria assim:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main() {
    int x, y, r = 0;
    cin >> x >> y;
    if (x < y) {
        for (; x < y; x++) if (x % 2 != 0) r += x;
    } else {
        for (; y < x; y++) if (y % 2 != 0) r += y;
    }
    cout << r << endl;
}
```

Veja [funcionando no **ideone**](https://ideone.com/BWYSGi). E [no **repl.it**](https://repl.it/join/lfmesgce-maniero). Também [coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/CPP/Algorithm/SumEven.cpp).

Dá para simplificar mais, mas provavelmente teria perda de performance, e alguns achariam menos legível.

Comment: Muito obrigado meu nobre, essa ideia de inicializar a variável eu desconhecia por completo.

Answer (score 1):

Você esqueceu de inicializar o `r`!

Então, a valor de `r` é sempre indeterminada e depende do que tem na memoria ao momento da sua alocação.

Muda sua inicialização:

```
int x,y,r;
```

em:

```
int x,y,r=0;
```

Comment: Acabei descobrindo por acaso isto, mas muito obrigado mesmo assim por compartilhar o conhecimento.